# What is difference between closed-set and open-set classification problem?

Tags: classification, face-recognition

What is difference between closed-set and open-set classification problem? Please explain in terms of face recognition problem.

Answer (score 1):

Open-set classification is a problem of handling unknown classes that are not contained in the training dataset, whereas traditional classifiers assume that only known classes appear in the test environment.